# Async call in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Working on MVC 4 application. I need to do certain DB calls with out blocking the current action method execution.

```
public ActionResult Save(Employee e){

  bool saveStatus = EmployeeService.Save(e);

  if(saveStatus){
   AuditService.Add("Employee {0} added successfully", e.Name); //want this async
  }
  return View(e);

}
```

In the above code I want to make the AuditService call to async.

The moment I save employee information i need to return the view instead of waiting for AuditService call.

I am new to `async` and `await` in MVC 4.

Comment: This code of yours is only handled async by the iis, so it doesn't waste a thread while it's waiting for the db call to finish. However ot will wait until the db call is finalized to find a new thread and than return the final result. Alternatively to Kamyar's answer, you could also consider AJAX

Answer (score 3):

As I describe on my blog, [`async` does not change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html). What you're asking for is how to return *early* from an HTTP request; this doesn't have anything to do with `async`/`await`.

Regarding returning early from HTTP requests: You almost *never* want to do this.

If your "audit" service is actually a log - **and** you are perfectly fine with the occasional log message *not* being logged - then (and *only* then) you can use an approach [like I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html).

Otherwise, you shouldn't return early. I.e., if your "audit" service is actually used for auditing, *or* if you expect your log to be accurate. In this case, you cannot return early.

Answer (score 2):

I think using `Task` is a better approach here:

```
if(saveStatus){
    new Task(AuditService.Add("Employee {0} added successfully", e.Name)).Start();
}
```

Update:
As Stephen pointed out in his answer, this may cause your in-progress work to be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You do it wrong. You can't run async inside any action of a simple controller. Because your client's code runs when server's code is completed and it isn't have the sense.

Depend on your target, you can do next:

- If you want to reduce the number of active connections, you have to use ASP.NET MVC asynchronous Controllers ([AsyncController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)). Check details by the next links: [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4), [Using Asynchronous Controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetmvc4_topic5.aspx), [Using an Asynchronous Controller in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). There described different ways to do it. Frankly, I haven't check every of these methods, so I share all.
- If you want to load some visual elements immediately and after this make call to your DB data, you have to move DB code under Ajax calls. Check details by the next links: [MVC JSON - JsonResult and jQuery](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx), [Json Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504936%28v=vs.98%29.aspx), [Using JsonResult with jquery in ASP.net MVC](http://shashankshetty.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/using-jsonresult-with-jquery-in-aspnet-mvc/)(with example). But I recommend you try asp.net mvc web api - [ASP.NET WEB API Basics (MVC 4)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/588909/ASP-NET-WEB-API-Basics-MVC-4), [Your First ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).